# Bigquery : COUNT/GROUP BY after regex extraction

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, count

I'm quite a newbie in bigquery. I have a table `MOVIES` with the following schema :

```
[SchemaField('movieId', 'INTEGER', 'NULLABLE', None, ()),
 SchemaField('title', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, ()),
 SchemaField('genres', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, ())]
```

The title of the movies looks like this : Pharaoh's Army (1995)

I want to see in which year most drama were filmed. I already managed to extract the year from the title and only keeping movies that are dramas like so :

```
q4 = """
select 
  movies.title,
  regexp_extract(title, r'\((\d{4})\)') as year,
from assignment-344206.movie_lens_20M.MOVIES movies
where movies.genres = "Drama"
order by year desc
limit 5
"""
query_job_4 = client.query(q4)
query_job_4.to_dataframe()
```

Now I need to group by year and then count each group to find the year with the most dramas. I tried this :

```
q4 = """
select 
  movies.title,
  regexp_extract(title, r'\((\d{4})\)') as year,
  count(year) as nb_per_year
from assignment-344206.movie_lens_20M.MOVIES movies
where movies.genres = "Drama"
group by year
order by year desc
limit 5
"""
```

But I get the following error `BadRequest: 400 Unrecognized name: year at [5:9]` which I don't understand. Without the `group by`the name `year` was recognized in `order by year desc`so why doesn't it recognize it now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement Martin Weitzmann answer, if you decide to go using `WITH`, below its a code/script implementation of such scenario. `with` can be use as a temp table in a single expression for your final query. For more details about `with` behaviour can be found on [with clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause) page.

**query**: This query shows the usage of `with` on your case. You can run this on the BigQuery UI.

```
with movies as (
    select 
        title,
        SAFE_CAST(regexp_extract(title, r'\((\d{4})\)') AS INT64) as year,
        genres
        from `projectid.datasetid.table`
)
select count(1) as movies_per_year, year
from movies
where genres = "Drama"
group by year
order by year desc
```

**code**: Replace *QUERY* with above query

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """ QUERY """

query_job = client.query(query)
df = query_job.to_dataframe()
print(df.head())
```

output

```
year | movier per year
2008 | 1
2003 | 1
2001 | 1
1994 | 2
1993 | 1
  ...
```

Comment: Oh I see ! Thank you very much Betjens and @Martin for your help, it really helped me understand the reasoning behind it !

Comment: I'm glad that you found the answers useful, please don't forget to upvote useful answers too.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregator `COUNT()` can't know `year` because you're only creating it in the line above as a category/group. `ORDER BY` gets executed after grouping/aggregations so it can know the field `year`.

Rough order of execution is afaik

1. FROM input tables
2. JOINs on table records
3. WHERE fields filter
4. GROUP BY aggregate fields
5. HAVING aggregates filter
6. WINDOW functions
7. QUALIFY window fields filter
8. DISTINCT result fields
9. ORDER BY result fields
10. LIMIT and OFFSET result rows
11. SELECT (output/print) output fields

(set operations like `UNION` only work with query results - not sure where to list them - either they're first or last depending on how you look at it)

Depending on whether there are NULL values in your `year` or not you could try `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(title)` or even `COUNT(regexp_extract(title, r'\((\d{4})\)'))`

If you don't want the extra regex but you need the field `year`, you can prepare the table in a CTE `WITH` and do the grouping in a query referencing the CTE.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer ! I do need the field year since I need to find which year has the most dramas (movies with the genre drama). However I'm not sure I understand the part about the table in a CTE. Sorry I'm completely new to this.